# Java server stops receiving updates and throws "IOException: server null error"

Tags: java, sockets, server, lan

I'm working on a Java LAN multiplayer application where the two players control ant colonies that fight each other. The script is set up in a way where both players possess a list of player one's ants and player two's ants. For every tick player one and player two exchange their respective lists.

This setup runs smoothly and accepts connections, but once two ants from opposite sides collide the two games unsync and throw "IOException: server null error". this causes both sides to stop receiving any updates from the other side.

I suspect this has something to do with safe thread structure but I have yet to find a way to solve this problem.

Here is my code (imports left out)

**Main.java**

```
public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
      System.out.print("Are you above a server (true/false)?");  
      Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);      
      boolean isServer = sc.nextBoolean();
      Frame frame = new Frame(isServer);
      frame.setSize(900, 500);
  }

}
```

**ServerTest.java**

```
public class ServerTest{
  private ArrayList<Ant> p1Ants;
  private ArrayList<Ant> p2Ants;
  
  private ServerSocket serverSocket;

  private Frame MyFrame;
  
  public ServerTest(){
    //server will send p1 ants and receive p2 ants
    try{
      serverSocket = new ServerSocket(6355);
    }
    catch (IOException e) {
      System.out.println("IOExpection server startup " + e.getMessage());
    }
  }

  public void send(ArrayList<Ant> list){
    try {
        System.out.println("sending");
        // Convert ArrayList to byte array
        ByteArrayOutputStream byteArrayOutputStream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
        ObjectOutputStream objectOutputStream = new ObjectOutputStream(byteArrayOutputStream);
        objectOutputStream.writeObject(list);
        objectOutputStream.flush();
        byte[] byteArray = byteArrayOutputStream.toByteArray();
        
        // Send byte array over the socket
        Socket socket = new Socket("localhost", 6455);
        System.out.println(socket.getRemoteSocketAddress().toString());
        OutputStream outputStream = socket.getOutputStream();
        outputStream.write(byteArray);
        outputStream.flush();
        System.out.println("ArrayList sent successfully.");
        
        socket.close();
    } 
    catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    
  }

  public ArrayList<Ant> receive(){
    try {
      System.out.println("Waiting for connection...");

      Socket clientSocket = serverSocket.accept();
      System.out.println("Connection established.");

      InputStream inputStream = clientSocket.getInputStream();
      byte[] receivedData = new byte[1024];
      int bytesRead = inputStream.read(receivedData);

      ByteArrayInputStream byteArrayInputStream = new ByteArrayInputStream(receivedData);
      ObjectInputStream objectInputStream = new ObjectInputStream(byteArrayInputStream);
      ArrayList<Ant> receivedArrayList = (ArrayList<Ant>) objectInputStream.readObject();
      
      p2Ants = receivedArrayList;
      
      return p2Ants;

    } 
    catch(ClassNotFoundException e){
      System.out.println("ClassNotFoundExpection");
      return null;
    }
    catch (IOException e) {
      System.out.println("IOExpection server "+ e.getMessage());
      return null;
    }
    
  }
  
}
```

**ClientTest.java (Same as ServerTest but swapped ports)**

```
public class ClientTest{
  private ArrayList<Ant> p1Ants;
  private ArrayList<Ant> p2Ants;
  
  private ServerSocket serverSocket;
  
  public ClientTest(){
    //Client will send p2 ants and receive p1 ants
    try{
      serverSocket = new ServerSocket(6455);
    }
    catch (IOException e) {
      System.out.println("IOExpection server startup " + e.getMessage());
    }
  }
  
 public void send(ArrayList<Ant> list){
    try {
        System.out.println("sending");
        // Convert ArrayList to byte array
        ByteArrayOutputStream byteArrayOutputStream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
        ObjectOutputStream objectOutputStream = new ObjectOutputStream(byteArrayOutputStream);
        objectOutputStream.writeObject(list);
        objectOutputStream.flush();
        byte[] byteArray = byteArrayOutputStream.toByteArray();
        
        // Send byte array over the socket
        Socket socket = new Socket("localhost", 6355);
        System.out.println(socket.getRemoteSocketAddress().toString());
        OutputStream outputStream = socket.getOutputStream();
        outputStream.write(byteArray);
        outputStream.flush();
        System.out.println("ArrayList sent successfully.");
        
        socket.close();
    } 
    catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    
  }

  public ArrayList<Ant> receive(){
    try {
      System.out.println("Waiting for connection...");

      Socket clientSocket = serverSocket.accept();
      System.out.println("Connection established.");

      InputStream inputStream = clientSocket.getInputStream();
      byte[] receivedData = new byte[1024];
      int bytesRead = inputStream.read(receivedData);

      ByteArrayInputStream byteArrayInputStream = new ByteArrayInputStream(receivedData);
      ObjectInputStream objectInputStream = new ObjectInputStream(byteArrayInputStream);
      ArrayList<Ant> receivedArrayList = (ArrayList<Ant>) objectInputStream.readObject();
      
      p1Ants = receivedArrayList;
      
      return p1Ants;

    } 
    catch(ClassNotFoundException e){
      System.out.println("ClassNotFoundExpection");
      return null;
    }
    catch (IOException e) {
      System.out.println("IOExpection client "+ e.getMessage());
      return null;
    }
    
  }  
}
```

**Frame.java**

```
public class Frame extends JPanel {

  private int HEIGHT = 500;
  private int WIDTH = 900;
  private JFrame APP;
  private boolean end = false;

  //server & client stuff
  private boolean isServer;
  private ServerTest server;
  private ClientTest client;

  // PLAYER1
  private ArrayList<Ant> p1Ants = new ArrayList<Ant>();
  private AntMound p1Mound;

  // PLAYER2
  private ArrayList<Ant> p2Ants = new ArrayList<Ant>();
  private AntMound p2Mound;
  
  //GUI
  private JButton upgradeCashPerSecond;
  private JButton upgradeCashPerKill;
  private JButton spawnRate;
  //GUI

  public Frame(boolean isSer) {
      
    setLayout(new FlowLayout()); 
      
    //server & client stuff
    isServer = isSer;
    if(isServer){
      server = new ServerTest();
    }
    else{
      client = new ClientTest();
    }
    
    // temp stuff
    p1Mound = new AntMound(100, 10.0, "p1", new FireAnt("p1"));
    p2Mound = new AntMound(100, 20.0, "p2", new BulletAnt("p2"));
    // temp stuff

    // Show frame
    APP = new JFrame("Hive Havoc");
    APP.pack();
    APP.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    APP.getContentPane().add(this);
    APP.setVisible(true);
    APP.setSize(WIDTH, HEIGHT);
    
    

    // GAME LOOP
    while (!end) {
      APP.repaint();
      sleep(100);
      //if client get p1 ants if server get p2 ants
      if(isServer){
         ArrayList<Ant> temp = p2Ants;
         p2Ants = server.receive();
         if(p2Ants == null)
            p2Ants = temp;
         server.send(p1Ants);
         
      }
      else{
         client.send(p2Ants);
         ArrayList<Ant> temp = p1Ants;
         p1Ants = client.receive();
         if(p1Ants == null)
            p1Ants = temp;
      }
      
    }

  }

  @Override
  protected void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
    super.paintComponent(g);
    System.out.println("Drawing and we are: " + isServer);
    
    
    if (p1Mound != null) {
      // draw p1 ants
      for (int i = 0; i < p1Ants.size(); i++) {
        Ant ant = p1Ants.get(i);
        ant.setImg();
        if(isServer){
          if (ant.getHealth() <= 0) {
            p1Ants.remove(i);
            p2Mound.getCash(10);
          } else if (p2Mound != null) {
            ant.moveAnt(p2Ants, p2Mound);
          }
        }
        ant.draw(g);
      }
    }
    if (p2Mound != null) {
      // draw p2 ants
      for (int i = 0; i < p2Ants.size(); i++) {
        Ant ant = p2Ants.get(i);
        ant.setImg();
        if(!isServer){
          if (ant.getHealth() <= 0) {
            p2Ants.remove(i);
            p1Mound.getCash(10);
          } else if (p1Mound != null) {
            ant.moveAnt(p1Ants, p1Mound);
          }
        }
        ant.draw(g);
      }
    }

    // spawn ants
    if (p1Mound != null && p1Mound.readyToSpawn() && isServer) {
      p1Ants.add(new Ant(p1Mound.getAnt().getHealth(), p1Mound.getAnt().getSpeed(), p1Mound.getAnt().getDamage(),
          p1Mound.getAnt().getName(), "p1"));
    }
    if (p2Mound != null && p2Mound.readyToSpawn() && !isServer) {
      p2Ants.add(new Ant(p2Mound.getAnt().getHealth(), p2Mound.getAnt().getSpeed(), p2Mound.getAnt().getDamage(),
          p2Mound.getAnt().getName(), "p2"));
    }

    // kil mounds
    if (p1Mound != null && p1Mound.getHealth() <= 0) {
      p1Mound = null;
      System.out.println("p1 dead");
      end = true;
    }
    if (p2Mound != null && p2Mound.getHealth() <= 0) {
      p2Mound = null;
      System.out.println("p2 dead");
      end = true;
    }

    // Draw mounds
    if (p1Mound != null) {
      p1Mound.draw(g);
    }
    if (p2Mound != null) {
      p2Mound.draw(g);
    }

  }

  public int getH() {
    return HEIGHT;
  }

  public int getW() {
    return WIDTH;
  }

  public ArrayList<Ant> getP1Ants() {
    return p1Ants;
  }

  public ArrayList<Ant> getP2Ants() {
    return p2Ants;
  }

  public void sleep(int T) {
    try {
      Thread.sleep(T);
    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
      e.printStackTrace();
    }
  }

}
```

**Ant.java**

```
public class Ant implements Serializable {
  private double health;
  private double speed;
  private double damage;
  private String name;
  private String player;
  private int ani_step = 0;
  private boolean ani_dir = true;
  private int x = 0;
  private int y = 0;
  private int rX = 0;
  private int rY = 0;
  private boolean atTarget = true;

  private int HEIGHT = 500;
  private int WIDTH = 900;
  
  private transient BufferedImage spriteSheet;

  private int size_cut = 4;

  public Ant(double h, double s, double d, String n, String play) {
    health = h;
    speed = s;
    damage = d;
    name = n;
    player = play;

    if(player.equals("p1")){
      //set p1 spawn
      x = 50;
      y = HEIGHT/2;
    }
    else{
      //set p2 spawn
      x = 850;
      y = HEIGHT/2;
    }

    try {
      spriteSheet = null;
    } catch (Exception v) {
      spriteSheet = null;
    }
  }
  
  public void setImg(){
   try {
      spriteSheet = ImageIO.read(new File("Sprites/"+ name + ".png"));
    } 
    catch (Exception v) {
      spriteSheet = null;
    }  
  }
  


  public void moveAnt(ArrayList<Ant> ants, AntMound antHill) {
    int antHillX = antHill.getX();
    int antHillY = antHill.getY();
    //System.out.println("HILL DIST: " + distanceToAnt(antHillX, antHillY));
    if (getNearestAnt(ants) != null &&  distanceToAnt(getNearestAnt(ants).getX(), getNearestAnt(ants).getY()) < 100) {
      // Move towards the nearest ant
      Ant nearestAnt = getNearestAnt(ants);
      int nearestAntX = nearestAnt.getX();
      int nearestAntY = nearestAnt.getY();
      moveTowards(nearestAntX, nearestAntY, ants);
    }
    else if (distanceToAnt(antHillX, antHillY) < 150){
      moveTowards(antHillX, antHillY, ants);
      rX = antHillX;
      rY = antHillY;
      if(distanceToAnt(antHillX, antHillY) <= 10){
        antHill.takeDamge();
      }
    }
    else{
      //RANDOM MOVEMENT
      if(distanceToAnt(rX,rY) < 10){
        atTarget = true;
        //System.out.println("at target");
      }
      if(atTarget){
        int nrX = (int) Math.floor(Math.random() *(WIDTH - 0 + 1) + 0);
        rY = (int) Math.floor(Math.random() *(HEIGHT - 0 + 1) + 0);
        if(player.equals("p1") && rX != 0){
          while(nrX < rX){
            nrX = (int) Math.floor(Math.random() *(WIDTH - 0 + 1) + 0);
          }
        }
        else if(rX != 0){
          while(nrX > rX){
            nrX = (int) Math.floor(Math.random() *(WIDTH - 0 + 1) + 0);
          }
        }
        rX = nrX;
        atTarget = false;
        //System.out.println("target is X:" + rX + " Y:" + rY);
      }
      
      moveTowards(rX, rY, ants);
    } 
    
  }

  private int distanceToAnt(int x, int y) {
    int dx = x - this.x;
    int dy = y - this.y;
    return (int) Math.sqrt(dx * dx + dy * dy);
  }

  private Ant getNearestAnt(ArrayList<Ant> ants) {
    Ant nearestAnt = null;
    double minDistance = Double.MAX_VALUE;

    for (Ant ant : ants) {
      int distance = distanceToAnt(ant.getX(), ant.getY());
      if (distance < minDistance) {
        minDistance = distance;
        nearestAnt = ant;
      }
    }

    return nearestAnt;
  }

  private void moveTowards(int targetX, int targetY, ArrayList<Ant> ants) {
    int dx = targetX - x;
    int dy = targetY - y;
    int distance = (int) Math.sqrt(dx * dx + dy * dy);

    if (distance > 0) {
      int nspeed = (int) speed/3;
      int moveX = (int) Math.round((double) dx / distance * nspeed);
      int moveY = (int) Math.round((double) dy / distance * nspeed);

      if (!isCollidingWithOtherAnt(ants)) {
        x += moveX;
        y += moveY;
      }
      else{
        //collision
        attackAnt(getNearestAnt(ants));
      }
    }
  }

  private boolean isCollidingWithOtherAnt(ArrayList<Ant> ants) {
    for (Ant ant : ants) {
      if (ant != this && isColliding(ant)) {
        return true;
      }
    }
    return false;
  }

  private boolean isColliding(Ant otherAnt) {
    int radius = 10; // Adjust the radius as needed for collision detection
    int dx = x - otherAnt.getX();
    int dy = y - otherAnt.getY();
    int distanceSquared = dx * dx + dy * dy;
    int minDistanceSquared = radius * radius * 4; // Adjust the factor (4) as needed for collision detection

    return distanceSquared < minDistanceSquared;
  }

  public BufferedImage getImg() {
    BufferedImage img = spriteSheet;
    BufferedImage new_img = spriteSheet;

    if (ani_step == 0)
      new_img = img.getSubimage(0, 0, 96, 101);
    else if (ani_step == 1)
      new_img = img.getSubimage(96, 0, 96, 101);
    else if (ani_step == 2)
      new_img = img.getSubimage(192, 0, 96, 101);
    else
      new_img = img.getSubimage(288, 0, 96, 101);

    if (ani_dir)
      ani_step++;
    else
      ani_step--;
    if (ani_step >= 4) {
      ani_dir = false;
    }
    if (ani_step <= 0) {
      ani_dir = true;
    }

    return new_img;
  }

  public void attackAnt(Ant ant) {
    ant.takeDamage(damage);
  }

  public void takeDamage(double amt) {
    health -= amt;
  }

  public double getHealth() {
    return health;
  }

  public double getSpeed() {
    return speed;
  }

  public double getDamage() {
    return damage;
  }

  public String getName() {
    return name;
  }

  public int getX() {
    return x;
  }

  public int getY() {
    return y;
  }

  public void draw(Graphics g) {
    g.drawImage(getImg(), x, y, getImg().getWidth() / size_cut, getImg().getHeight() / size_cut, null);
    g.drawLine(rX,rY,x,y+10);
  }

}
```

There are some other dependencies such as BulletAnt.java, FireAnt.java, and AntMound.java but I didn't think they were relevant to the issue, but let me know if would help to see them.

Any and all help would be greatly appreciated. Thank you in advance!

Comment: That's a lot of code. Please read about how to produce a [mre], having one makes it a lot easier for people to help you.

Comment: `while (!end) {` and ... no - most defiantly not within a context of Swing app. Swing is not thread safe and is single threaded.  You've actually lucked out not locking your app up. Take some time to have a look at [Concurrency in Swing](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/index.html) and consider using a [Swing `Timer`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/timer.html) for the main game loop and a [`SwingWorker`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/worker.html) to handle the comms

Comment: I'm also confused why you would do `Socket socket = new Socket("localhost", 6355);` each time you call `send`. The point is, you get a client socket in `receive`, shouldn't you be using this socket to send data back?

Comment: Thank you @MadProgrammer, I'll make sure to look into what you mentioned about concurrency in swing.